# Regex that negates a whole word

Tags: java, regex

I have the following scenario where I need to extract the RAM value from string like the following:

```
1GB, 4GB ROM Android 5.1 3G
```

The `RAM` value is `1GB`

Currenlty , I m using the following regex:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s?([Gg])[Bb]
```

However, in this case I also get the `4GB` value which corresponds to the `ROM` value. How can I write the regex so that it doesnt match when the `ROM` word follows?

Thank you

Comment: What if the ROM word does not follow? Does your input always follow this format? Can you just take the first match on the line?

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks for your reply. Actually, I cannot rely on that cause RAM does not always comes first

Answer (score 5):

Use a negative lookahead

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s?([Gg])[Bb](?!\s?[Rr][Oo][Mm])
```

The `(?!\s?[Rr][Oo][Mm])` part means the following string must not match `\s?[Rr][Oo][Mm]`.

You may want to consider using the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag instead of the character groups, btw.

Comment: Thns Fabian, it works fine. As a follow up , If ROM precedes the value, what would the regex look like then?

Comment: @panipsilos `(?<![Rr][Oo][Mm]\s?)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s?([Gg])[Bb]` (negative lookbehind)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following negative lookahead:

```
(?i)\d+Gb(?!\s*ROM)
```

It will match digits followed by Gb but not ROM

Comment: Thnx Thomas, your answer works as well. I can only choose one so I  chose fabian since here replied first. However, I upvoted yours as well